# Different errors on different browsers with Media Source Extension of HTML Video tag

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video-streaming, html5-video

So I'm trying to get a video to play using Media Source APIs in my HTML page. I have a NodeJS server that serves me a video file of about 30MB.

Below is my server code:

```
const fileMap = {
    "1": "sample.mp4"
}

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let range = req.headers.range;
        let fileName = fileMap[req.query.file];
        console.log("Range", range);
        console.log('Filename: ' + fileName);
        const movieSize = await movieService.getMovieSize(fileName);
        if (range) {
            console.info('Range Found');
            const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
            const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[0], 10) : movieSize - 1;
            console.log("Start: ", start);
            console.log("End: ", end);
            let readStream = await movieService.getMovieFileReadStream(fileName, start, end);
            if (start >= movieSize) {
                res.status(416).send('Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            }
            const chunkSize = (end - start) + 1;
            const head = {
                "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${movieSize}`,
                "Accept-Ranges": 'bytes',
                "Content-Length": chunkSize,
                "Content-Type": 'video/mp4'
            }
            res.writeHead(200, head);
            readStream.pipe(res);
        } else {
            console.log('No range received');
            const head = {
                "Content-Length": movieSize,
                "Content-Type": 'video/mp4'
            };
            res.writeHead(200, head);
            let readStream = await movieService.getMovieFileReadStream(fileName)
            readStream.pipe(res);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error while processing Movie request:\n", err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
})
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Sample Page
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="videoplayer" controls width="80%" muted="muted"></video>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    console.log('In Here')

    let url = '/v1/movies?file=1';
    let sourceBuffer;
    let mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    
    onLoad();

    function onLoad() {
        console.info('OnLoad called');

        if (!window.MediaSource) {
            let message = 'MediaSource not supported by current browser';
            console.error(message);
            return;
        }

        if (!window.MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
            let message = 'Code not supported by MediaSource';
            console.error(message);
            return;
        }

        console.log('So FAr')
        let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleOpen.bind(mediaSource));
    }

    function handleOpen() {
        let mediaSource = this;
        console.log("Open State");
        console.log('Ready: ', mediaSource.readyState);
        sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        addToSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Whammy');
            }
            mediaSource.endOfStream();
            video.play().then(resolved => {
                console.log(resolved)
            }).catch(err => console.error(err))
        })
    }


    function addToSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer, callback) {
        getChunk(function(buff) {
            console.log("Received Buffer: ", buff);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buff);

            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function() {
                console.log('Source Buffer Update has ended');
                callback();
            });

            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', function(err) {
                console.error('Error Ocurred')
                callback(err);
            })
        })
    }

    function getChunk(callback) {
        console.log("Calling URL: ", url)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function() {
            callback(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send()
    }

</script>

</html>
```

When I run this with **Firefox 79.0 (64bit)**, I get `Uncaught DOMException: The Quota has been exceeded` error.

I don't understand why it happens because according to the logs, I have already received the file as array buffer at this line `Received Buffer:  ArrayBuffer(31491130) {}`.

Am I putting too much data at a time? According to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/quotaexceedederror), Firefox can handle upto 100MB and my file is just 30+ MB.

[image: Image Attached of the console log]

Why's my video not playing then?

On Chrome 84, I get a different `DOMException`

```
(index):57 DOMException: The element has no supported sources.
```

This happens when I try `video.play()` in my HTML code.

[image: this]

Where am I going wrong? In both cases, I am not able to play the video. I have read about using MSE with media segments using DASH, but I just wanted to try out raw Media Source Extension without any DASH for now just to get it working.

But different errors on different browsers got me confused. I followed [this](https://medium.com/@eyevinntechnology/how-to-build-your-own-streaming-video-html-player-6ee85d4d078a) tutorial

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first problem is your video.

I used ffmpeg to recode my video:

```
ffmpeg -i "v.mp4" -vcodec copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 48k -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof+omit_tfhd_offset "V2.mp4"
```

the important thing is `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof+omit_tfhd_offset`
I get it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API/Transcoding_assets_for_MSE

Also useful this one `chrome://media-internals/` to see what happened.